# How do stack traces get generated?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

No single method in a program "knows" where it is on the stack.  All it knows is its own little job, and it does that and returns.  So when an Exception is thrown and a stack trace is printed, where does this come from?

Is there implicitly a separate Thread running alongside of every application in the JVM that's monitoring the state of the program?  Or does the JVM itself hold this information and the Exceptions somehow pull that data from it when they are thrown?

If either of these is the case, is it possible to use some call to retrieve a stack trace (either from the monitor Thread or the JVM) *without* throwing an Exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every thread will have its own `stack`. Each method call creates a stack frame. If something wrong happened in code of any method, that will propagated to caller method. This way JVM can trace which method generated error and what is the call hierarchy.

If you observe the stack trace properly, you will see the method where error occured at top and the hierarchy in bottom.

There is a great lecture in [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8nNdNZ40EQ&feature=relmfu) by a Stanford professor to understand how does it work. I would suggest watching it.

NOTE: This is theory. If you would like to know how API works, @Peter Lawrey answer may help you.

Comment: Yes, I'm very interested in the theory. :)  That's why I asked the question, not for any particular practical purpose.

Comment: Ok, then my answer may give some leads and the video series may fill-in the gaps.

Answer (score 4):

It comes from the Thread class that is running through the code.

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

To see it you can just:

```
    StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i=0; i < trace.length; i++)
        System.out.println("\tat " + trace[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can know the Thread a method belongs to by using `Thread.currentThread`. Using this thread, you can get the StackTrace, because there is a stack for every thread in the JVM. Also, the `main` program runs in the `main` thread.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a Throwable (not when you throw it) it records the stack trace is a low level/hidden way associated with the Throwable. When you call getStackTrace() the first time it creates the `StackTraceElement[]` objects from the low level information.  It doesn't this lazily as the stack trace is often not used.