# How are stack traces built and how is the stack kept track of?

Tags: programming-languages, stack-trace

*Context:* I'm building a programming language (called Lima), and I want to know what options there are to have the system keep track of the stack such that I can generate proper stack traces (with the right line-numbers from the original source). Note that this is not meant to be a duplicate of this related but limited question: [How do stack traces get generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865180/how-do-stack-traces-get-generated)

My fundamental questions is: Does the program need to make an update as to what line number it is on between every line executed?

It seems to me that the unfortunate answer here is yes.

I'm also wondering whether I can leverage anything in the environment I'm compiling to for stack traces. Right now I'm compiling the language to javascript (and running in Rhino) - but I'm looking for a general answer as to whether its even theoretically possible for the underlying environment to help you in any way here.

If the underlying system supports stack traces, can you make a static mapping from that system's line numbers to yours?

Comment: Does the person that voted to close this want to give a hint as to what they're thinking?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the stack has the return address stored as each subroutine call is made. That address is used in a symbol lookup when generating the stack trace. For a scripting language I guess you'd have to obtain the file and line number / line position when making a subroutine call and put it on the stack. I'm guessing that scripting languages would construct a hash table to lookup this information to keep the actual stack more compact.

Comment: So your answer to my basic question is yes - that at minimum I'll have to add or remove some hash values (that point to line numbers and other meta information) on every function call?

Comment: One of your parsing steps must already be generating a similar hash table as it figures out where all the subroutine calls are?

Comment: Not currently. I may not be building a compiler-as-you-know-it. At the moment the "compiler" translates the language into javascript - the execution of which probably takes care of whatever hash table you're assuming I need. But maybe I'm not understanding you right?